# Perl Search between key words

Tags: perl, search

Okay, so let's say I have the following in a file I'm reading in:

```
File:foobarbar.xml
abc
def
ghi
File:barbar.xml
jkl
mno
```

I would like for the output to be:

```
foobarbar
barbar
```

But for some reason I'm only getting

```
foobarbar
```

I am using the following code:

```
if (/File([\s\S]+?)xml/) {
    $key= $1; 
    print OUTPUT "$key\n"
}
```

Note: in the above code, `$key` is set to `$number one`, not `$lower case letter L`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: btw, `/[\s\S]/` is the same as `/./s`

Answer (score 2):

that regex only matches the first file, use the /g modifier to get all matches

```
while (/File:(.*)\.xml/g) {
    $key = $1;
    print OUTPUT "$key\n";
}
```

Comment: That assumes you have slurped the entire file into `$_` which isn't the usual situtuation.

Comment: Well he didn't specify how he was reading the file in. If he has the whole thing slurped into $_, he can use my solution. Otherwise he can use perreal's solution all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Code below works as expected when you read the input line by line:

```
while(<>) {
  if (/File:([\s\S]+?)\.xml/){
    $key= $1; 
    print "$key\n";
  }
}
```